# Virtualmin : multiple subdomains to single directory

Tags: linux, .htaccess, webmin

I'm trying to point all my subdomains to a single directory. For instance...

- en.mywebsite.com
- de.mywebsite.com
- uk.mywebsite.com

...must point to /home/mywebsite/public_html

This way, I want to catch the subdomain each time and update the language. (this is just an example, don't try to give another solution about languages)

I'm using Virtualmin and I don't know how to configure this.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it's in Create Virtual Server > Create an Alias of mywebsite.com. Then you have to point the new subdomain to the same IP.